# Raise error in create method django rest framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I throw `ValidationError` while validating data in my `clean` method in `models.py`. How can I catch this error in my custom `create` method so that it throws a json object containing the error detail in this
way

```
{
    "detail":"input is not valid"
}
```

```py
#models.py
class Comment(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    commenter = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)

    def clean(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if containsBadWords(text):
            raise ValidationError(_("Be Polite"))
#serializer.py
def create(self, validated_data):
    request = self.context.get('request', None)
    commenter = request.user
    try:
        obj = Comment.objects.create(
            post = validated_data['post'],
            commenter = commenter,
            text = validated_data['text']
        )
    except ValidationError as ex:
        raise ex
    return obj
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Check that you have thrown `serializers.ValidationError` not `ValidationError` of `django.core.exceptions`. You can change your `create` method in this way:

```py
def create(self, validated_data):
    request = self.context.get('request', None)
    commenter = request.user
    try:
        obj = Comment.objects.create(
            post = validated_data['post'],
            commenter = commenter,
            text = validated_data['text']
        )
    except ValidationError as ex:
        raise serializers.ValidationError({"detail": "input is not valid"})
    return obj
```

Comment: we do have the `validate` method also, right? how can we grab *authenticated* `user_id` and `validate` I did search a lot but many of them used `self.context['request'].user` but it's totally wrong